# C# MVVM - Is a model required here?

Tags: c#, mvvm

So I am delving into MVVM using C# with WPF (using Expression Blend) and have run into a question of how to properly implement the gathering of data from a database and displaying it in a window.

My view is just a grid with a few TextBlocks that I can update with data from a SQL query (I am reporting the number of calls that were made to our company and by our phone agents, so All Calls, Incoming Calls, etc.)

My question is, do I need a model here to get/hold the data or is it good (or at acceptable) MVVM practice to do this in the ViewModel?  If I do it in the VM I can easily implement the INotifyPropertyChanged event and everything works.  If I create a model to hold the data do I then have to create an INotifyPropertyChanged in the Model and the VM or is there something else that should be used to do the notifications?

This seems like a straight forward task but I just can't seem to find a good example of just displaying pieces of data, every example I find is of a collection and being my first MVVM program I want to make sure I do it right :)

I read on another post someone saying "every Model requires a VM but not every VM requires a Model".  This goes along with my question above and would just like to hear the thoughts of some experienced users.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *should" have a model, which you *should* think of as two separate pieces:
1) a domain sort of object which encapsulates business rules and logic (ie, Customer)
2) some data access sort of object which encapsulates data retrieval (ie, CustomerDao or CustomerRepository)

Both of these should be injected into your view model constructor, as opposed to newing them up somewhere inside of the view model:

```
class CustomerViewModel(Customer customer, CustomerDao){...}
```

You *should* be testing even if it seems trivial; if it only needs one or two tests to prove it works, great.

HTH,
Berryl

Comment: I agree I should be testing and know about red-green-re-factor but I am not sure what I should be testing here.  If all I am doing is getting data from the database (which isn't unit testing, rather integration testing) and then displaying the data what kind of tests should I be doing here?

Comment: Without knowing your use case, I can think of the following view model tests re: how it consumes data. And yes, it's a unit test, so mock or fake the data. First, have a test that ensures a null data access object (dao) throws an error. Second, have a test that the appropriate method on your dao is called, perhaps it is dao.FindAll(). That might be enough for now, although as you think about how your data is being consumed you will think of others. Ask questions and post some code if you need more help. Cheers

Comment: @BrianKE - Integration testing is good, but combining integration tests and unit testing is critical for a DB. Part of having a model allows you to implement the kind of abstractions that you use to separate the db from the model so you can unit test. Like I state in my primary answer, if you aren't going to test, then don't worry about it. Of course you should be unit testing, and integration testing, but if you didn't commit to that work at the start of the project it would be better to deliver, and account for testing work next iteration, release, or project. Shipping is a feature.

Answer (score 0):

MVVM is not a strict pattern. You can do which ever feels right for your situation.

There are some people who will say that the Model should not implement INotifyPropertyChanged, but I seem no logical reason behind this.

I would suggest that for a simple example as you describe go with a single VM, no model and populate the properties directly in the VM.

You should go to a full View-ViewModel-Model pattern where you have a single or few models, with multiple views over it, then you would need multiple ViewModels, one per View.

I have implement MVVM where the VM had a web service reference and pulled its model from the web service, you could say that your DataSet coming from the Sql query is the model and wrap the ViewModel around the data in the DataSet.

Comment: I'm not following this statement, can you expand on it? "You should go to a full View-ViewModel-Model pattern where you have a single or few models, with multiple views over it, then you would need multiple ViewModels, one per View."

Comment: Basically I am saying for a simple scenario a single model might not be required, however if you have multiple views sharing data, then a single common model is definitely required

Comment: But when you populate the properties directly in the VM the data has to come from any other object. So what is the difference between a model and "the other object" that acts as a model in your "lightweight" scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some sort of model, even if its just a simple class so that you can abstract out the database (probably with an interface) and test from the VM down to the methods that interact with the dB.  There are other benefits to implementing a MVVM structure. It provides separation of concerns, clearer logic, and possible code reuse.

My response to your question is, "are you going to test?" If not, then you don't need a model. Put the code into your VM and deliver your project. If you are going to test, introduce a model.